# Unix command to cut between strings

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, cut

my file:

```
Informatica(r) PMCMD, version [10.2.0 HotFix2], build [1911.0401],  Workflow run status: [Failed]
```

Output I need is `Failed`

Output I am getting is `10.2.0 HotFix2`

Command used:

```
grep "Workflow run status:" test.txt | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1
```

---

If Workflow run status: comes in any field, my objective is to search Workflow run status: and then print the status of the field. Because Workflow run status: can come in any line or field

Comment: @JeffSchaller, why remove the arch-linux and historical-unix tags (which better identify OSes and give clues as to what text processing  utility implementations may be available to the OP (though the combination of those two tags is rather confusing)) and add the linux tag which is irrelevant as it only identified a kernel which is irrelevant here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas we don't get very many historical-unix questions, so in combination with the arch-linux tag, I assumed it was a mistaken tag.  I am trying to keep up with [Meta guidance](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5469/117549) (and previous linked discussions) on the Linux tag. Since none of the question seemed specific to Arch, I removed that one and left Linux as an indication of the operating environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut -d'[' -f2` gets you the second `[` delimited field. In

```
Informatica(r) PMCMD, version [10.2.0 HotFix2], build [1911.0401],  Workflow run status: [Failed]
<---------- field 1 ---------> <------ field 2 ------> <------------ field 3 -----------> <field 4>
```

You'd rather want the fourth field if its `Failed` you want. However, using `sed` to extract the part after `Workflow run status` would make more sense:

```
sed -n 's/^.*Workflow run status: \[\([^]]*\)\].*$/\1/p' < file
```

Or as the original tags on your questions suggest you're on a GNU system, get GNU `grep` to extract it with:

```
grep -Po 'Workflow run status: \[\K[^]]*' < file
```

Those would extract the part in `Workflow run status: [there]` without having to rely on how many `[`s there were on the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "[,:]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /Workflow run status/){gsub(/[\[\]]/,"",$(i+1));print $(i+1)}}}' filename



 output

 Failed
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works?